# Number and size of dense layers in a CNN

Tags: convolutional-neural-network

Most networks I've seen have one or two dense layers before the final softmax layer.

- Is there any principled way of choosing the number and size of the dense layers?
- Are two dense layers more representative than one, for the same number of parameters?
- Should dropout be applied before each dense layer, or just once?

Comment: I am also interested in this topic.
While @moh did answer some questions, one is left: - Is there any principled way of choosing the number and size of the dense layers? Reference 6 link is broken. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 22):

First of all:

> There is no way to determine a good network topology just from the
>   number of inputs and outputs. It depends critically on the number of
>   training examples and the complexity of the classification you are
>   trying to learn.[1]

and Yoshua Bengio has proposed a very simple rule:

> Just keep adding layers until the test error does not improve anymore.[2]

Moreover:

> The earlier features of a ConvNet contain more generic features (e.g.
>   edge detectors or color blob detectors) that should be useful to many
>   tasks, but later layers of the ConvNet becomes progressively more
>   specific to the details of the classes contained in the original
>   dataset.[3]

For example, in a method for learning feature detectors:

> first layer learns edge detectors and subsequent layers learn more complex features, and higher level layers encode more abstract features. [4]

So, using two dense layers is more advised than one layer.

Finally:

> The original paper on Dropout provides a number of useful heuristics to consider when using dropout in practice. One of them is:
>    **Use dropout on incoming (visible) as well as hidden units. Application of dropout at each layer of the network has shown good results.** [5]

in CNN, usually, a Dropout layer is applied after each pooling layer, and also after  your Dense layer. A good tutorial is here [6]

**References:**

[1] https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/util/html/faqs/ai/neural/faq.html

[2] Bengio, Yoshua. "Practical recommendations for gradient-based training of deep architectures." Neural networks: Tricks of the trade. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2012. 437-478.

[3] http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/

[4] http://learning.eng.cam.ac.uk/pub/Public/Turner/Teaching/ml-lecture-3-slides.pdf

[5] https://machinelearningmastery.com/dropout-regularization-deep-learning-models-keras/

[6] https://cambridgespark.com/content/tutorials/convolutional-neural-networks-with-keras/index.html

Answer (score -1):

1 layer gives linear approximation (can use if need linear regression)

2 & more layers provide non-linearity... e.g. 2 provide in results speed & acceleration

Comment: 1 layer gives non-linearity if you count the activation function - logistic regression is a dense layer + sigmoid. 2 layers does not make things faster; it makes a more complex model.

Comment: non-linear activation function does NOT lead to non-linearity of the resulting Approximation, because **y=weight*x+bias** is Linear function, that is achieved by error minimization as a result of applying Dense layer (through any activation function). Activation function just makes weightening, but resulting fuction of dependency (**y=f(x)**) is linear function, when 1 Dense layer used

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say, but an activation function is not a weight. In fact, composing 2 linear transformations just results in a linear transformation; the activation function is what makes this simple network setup non-linear.

Comment: [Activation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function) - "each neuron forms a weighted sum of its inputs" & then AF works with this vector... But each W at each point is just the slope of tangent (or speed). But using 2*Dense -- you get W^2 further on (meaning acceleration)... and only after applying AF (depending on its nature) it gives linearity or non-linearity of the final result... -- *this what I meant*

Comment: BTW, depending on AF choice - depends **derivative** values (as is *slope* for every 2nd-order polinomial or W^2 part in intermediary input)... - as is for any point-curvature)... and vanishing  gradient (dy/dx) problem also concerns the choice of AF -- but this is out of this question's concern

Comment: concerning "*any principle way of choosing the number and size of the dense layers?*" - I suppose to *1st Q* - depends on goals of the model - with more Dense layers can get more precise results, but models with many layers suffer from vanishing gradient & overfitting, - experiment with diff. qty of layers & see better ROC curves (as for imbalanced ds) , not precision, to summarize the performance of classifier - & choose the best model that suits your goals. To *2nd Q* - with too huge output units - you can get stuck at local minimum (I didn't test)  -  recommended 60% of previous layer